# Angular routing : how can I redirect all unknown nested routes to one component?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Currently I have the following router :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'presentation', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'presentation', component: PresentationPageComponent },
  { path: 'news', component: NewsPageComponent }, {
    path: 'tools', component: ToolsPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'unit-selector', component: UnitSelectorComponent },
      { path: 'object-selector', component: ObjectSelectorComponent },
    ] },
  { path: 'games', component: GamesPageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: Error404PageComponent }
];
```

My problem is two-fold :

The router correctly redirects all bad routes such as `mydomain.com/badRoute` and `myDomain.com/incorrectRoute` to the Error404PageComponent but as soon as the routes become nested such as `mydomain.com/badRoute/random` or `mydomain.com/badRoute/stuff` or even on valid nested routes such as `mydomain.com/tools/unit-selector` the web navigator ( tried both Firefox and Edge ) display a white screen and errors in the console ( resource being blocked due to incorrect MIME type )

The route `mydomain.com/tools` works properly and displays the Error404PageComponent within the ToolsPageComponent

How can I get my routes to work properly ?

Note : I am using WebStorm IDE to run the website locally ( it has no server / backend )

Here is a picture of the error ( this only happens on nested routes ) :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have two `{ path: '**', component: Error404PageComponent }` in your `app-routing.module.ts`. Remove `{ path: '**', component: Error404PageComponent }` from children routes and just keep the last one in the `Routes`. It will be ok.

I crated a ample for you here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/routing-example-i4h6xd?file=app/header/header.component.html). The 3rd Tab `undefined route` in my sample is a multiple undefined route like `"/home/page1/undefined/nested/route"` and if you click on that tab you will be redirected to `home` component correctly.

Comment: This does not seem to make any difference for my current issue ( I am using WebStorm IDE if the information can be of any help ). I will edit my question to include your answer as it does seem to be a good idea to me

Comment: Check my sample on Stackblitz

Comment: I can see it works but I cannot understand why mine does not; I keep getting MIME errors and I do not understand what is causing them

Comment: What is the Error? Add the error message to your question that can help you.

Comment: sure, I will add a screen now

Comment: added the picture

Comment: That's your server failing to serve `.js` files correctly. It should say `application/javascript` for `Content-Type`.

Comment: But your solution works on that same server so the problem comes from my code, I will have to look into it closely. Will keep you updated and thanks for the help ( I am going to check all of the differences one by one )